# What is a Fantastical Word™?

Tags: pattern, english, word-property, video-games

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Fantastical Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

[image: Fantastical Words]

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Fantastical Words™,Not Fantastical Words™
AKIN,DISSIMILAR
SOAR,FALL
DIARY,JOURNAL
LETHAL,BENIGN
RATER,GRADER
GRADE,CATEGORY
BASIN,PLATE
ZESTER,PEELER
GATORS,CROCS
AMOUR,HATRED
COULD,SHOULD
FIAT,DENIAL
BARTER,PURCHASE
NORIA,DRAIN
VINIER,BRANCH
DRAW,ERASE
LADE,UNLOAD
MARANTA,COCONUT
FAERY,BUTTERFLY
JAUK,HURRY
YUAN,DOLLAR
KUKRI,RAPIER
SHEA,PEANUT
NARF,CONQUER
SOLVERS,PUZZLERS
DREADS,WELCOMED
SHEAR,GROW
OWNS,DESIRES
LONE,GROUPED
TONICS,POISON
ISOLEAD,SQUARE
VARUS,REGULAR
```

Comment: I feel like these are all names of games but I don't have the time to look them all up :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each Fantastical Word:

> Is an anagram of a Final Fantasy Character.

Explanation of each:

> AKIN -> KAIN, the Dragoon from FF4
> SOAR -> ROSA, white mage from FF4
> DIARY -> RYDIA, summoner from FF4
> LETHAL -> TELLAH, mage from FF4
> RATER -> TERRA, from FF6
> GRADE -> EDGAR, from FF6
> BASIN -> SABIN, from FF6
> ZESTER -> SETZER, from FF6
> GATORS -> STRAGO, from FF6
> AMOUR -> UMARO, from FF6
> COULD -> CLOUD, from FF7
> FIAT -> TIFA, from FF7
> BARTER -> BARRET, from FF7
> NORIA -> RINOA, from FF8
> VINIER -> IRVINE, from FF8
> DRAW -> WARD, from FF8
> LADE -> ADEL, from FF8
> MARANTA -> AMARANT, from FF9
> FAERY -> FREYA, from FF9
> JAUK -> KUJA, from FF9
> YUAN -> YUNA, from FF10
> KUKRI -> RIKKU, from FF10
> SHEA -> ASHE, from FF12
> NARF -> FRAN, from FF12
> SOLVERS -> VOSSLER, from FF12
> DREADS -> REDDAS, from FF12
> SHEAR -> SERAH, from FF13
> OWNS -> SNOW, from FF13
> LONE -> NOEL, from FF13-2
> TONICS -> NOCTIS, from FF15
> ISOLEAD -> IEDOLAS, from FF15
> VARUS -> RAVUS, from FF15

Comment: Well that took less time than expected

Comment: @DavidStarkey looking at some of the previous questions pointed me in the right direction, and this theme touches on one of my favorite things.

Comment: You should probably add the trivia tag? That would've been hard if he didn't know about FF

Comment: @Areeb I figured the video-game tag would be sufficient, but if you think it needs it feel free to edit it in

Comment: Nah, it can't be. There's no appearance by Biggs *or* Wedge.

Comment: @DavidStarkey Id forgotten that one was there, when i posted my comment, someone had removed it